# Inserting a single value at a specific location in a 2D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I am trying to program a game of Connect 4, and I need to insert a "#" in a specific (row,col) on the board. Please could someone explain how I'd insert this value into that location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:  ???

```
 import numpy as np

 board=np.zeros([8, 8], dtype=np.character)
 print board
 board[3, 4]="#"
 print board
```

...or what else is your problem?